# Can a 12V power supply provide more than the rated current at lower voltages?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-regulator, 12v, 5v

This might be a silly question but if I'm using a 12V power supply rated to provide 5A does that mean that if I was to regulate the voltage down to 5V I could theoretically draw 12A at 5V?

If Watt = Amp X Voltage, then the supply should be apply to provide 60W in any configuration of amps and Volts(provided the voltage is under 12V)

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, theoretically. Practically there will be loss in the conversion. Note, that linear regulators won't do the trick, you need a switching one.

Comment: Normally No,  unless the spec says so.

Comment: Look into the data sheet. Most power supplies can't do this, but for those who can it will be mentioned.

Comment: Seems like we have different understanding of the question.. Are you talking about adjustable power supply alone, or a power supply and some kind of circuit to regulate it's output?

Comment: Not likely.  Some components of the power supply may be limited by current, not power.  This depends a lot on the design of the power supply.

Comment: on a linear power supply, amps are the same top to bottom. on a switch mode, you can get current multiplication at lower output voltages. a good sync-mode buck with generous inductors can preserve ~98% of the watts at 5v.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm talking about a power supply and a circuit to regulate it's output. I don't really need a perfect 1:1 conversion but just to ensure I can draw more amps at a lower voltage, given ofcourse that the regulator can handle it

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was planning on using 2xLM2596 switching regulators both connected to the same 12v input power supply. They can output upto 3A each and I would regulate them down to 5V. I wanted to ensure the 12V 5A supply could provide the theoretical max output of 6A total from the 2 regulators at 5V.

Answer (score 2):

No regulator is perfect,  and you will not get 100% efficiency. In general, it is Power in - inefficiency = power out, when using a switching buck or step down regulator. Average efficiency is 80 to 90%, so you could get 10.8 amps at 5V from a 60W supply input.

Comment: 12A must use a very low RDSon mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not.

For linear supplies, the lower the output voltage the greater the power dissipated by the regulator.

For switching supplies, inductor/transformer saturation is usually the limiting factor, and this is largely independent of output voltage.

Comment: I guess I framed by question incorrectly. I'm not looking for a precise 1:1 conversion. I was planning on using 2XLM2596 switching regulators which can output 3A each at 5V. I wanted to ensure that a 12V 5A supply could supply 6A at 5V.

Comment: Yes a 60w supply could with the correct regulator provide a 30W output. Those two seem appropriate but you are better off getting a 7 amp or higher regular instead of 2 small ones. If you need 6 amps, get a slightly bigger regulator as a margin of safety.

Comment: @Passerby another reason for using 2 regulators was to reduce noise in the circuit. I have a Raspberry Pi and an amplifier connected to speakers which is picking up a lot of noise. It does reduce if I use an LC filter but only really goes away if I power the pi and amplifier separately and share ground between the two. I was thinking I could use one regulator for the amplifier and one for the Pi and this will hopefully help reduce the noise.

Comment: That's a legit use case.

Answer (score 0):

No. This means the power supply is designed to produce 12V constantly, up to a maximum of 5A. It will not output other voltages.

If you connected it to a 0.4167 ohm resistor (which would draw 12A at 5V, or 28.8A at 12V) it may (depending on the quality) turn itself off, output only 0.1 volts, make a strange noise, go bang and/or catch fire.

Yes. You can add a *second* conveter, after this one, to convert 12V to 5V and you will be able to get 11-ish A out of *that* one. The output of your main power supply would be the input of your second power supply. Or you could get one that outputs 5V to start with.